# Cleartool move moves only top directory

Tags: version-control, clearcase, mv

We're trying to move a bunch of folders from one location to another in our vob. The process is that:

- we check out the target parent folder
- check out the source parent parent folder
- ct mv source target

This unfortunately fails with moving only the top folder in the tree... On the other hand ct relocate works fine and we avoid checking out thousands of vob elements. Are there any drawbacks with that command? We assume that the source and the target are in the same vob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We assume that the source and the target are in the same vob.

Then `cleartool mv` is enough: see "[To move an element within a VOB](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_dev/to_move_withinvob.htm?lang=en)"

It won't move just the top element.

As mentioned in "[Relocating elements to another VOB](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_relo.htm?lang=en)":

> The `relocate` command does not do any of the following:
>
> - Relocate elements when either the source or the target VOB is a UCM component VOB or PVOB.
> - Move view-private files and nonversioned DOs stored in relocated directories.
> - **Move elements to a new location in the same VOB. (Use `cleartool mv` for this purpose.)**

Comment: Thanks VonC! The symptom why we think mv is not enough is that after the command, ls in the new location show nothing in the moved folder. Does it mean that we're not working with the same VOB?

Comment: @zeller or it could means that the content of the source folder wasn't yet added to source control (a `cleartool ls` in the source folder *before* the move can help to see what is going on)

Comment: they're under version control. So they're in different VOBs and our assumption was bad, no other possibilities right?

Comment: @zeller if they are in different vobs, then yes, the assumption was incorrect, and `cleartool relocate` is the right tool.