# ClearCase Common Workflow Example

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I am working with ClearCase and I am very new to the tool. I find it confusing and cumbersome compared to other source control, like git with svn, for example. I was wondering if someone could walk through a typical workflow. So right now we have a main integration stream, then a child stream on that, then from there child streams for each project.

Use Case 1:

I check in a file and want everyone to get changes. I have to first add to ClearCase or check in, then I have to deliver to each stream above me (twice), then I would create a baseline and do a rebase to cascade the changes back down. Is this correct?

Use Case 2:

If I forget what changes I made, is there a mechanism to see all the files I modified? and check them all in at once.

Use Case 3:

If I want to modify a file, do I always have to check it out?

Use Case 4:

If I move a file, must I remove it from clear case and then re-add it? Or what about if I just want to rename a package or file?

Use Case 5:

Right now I have a dynamic view on the main integration stream, then child views in between. If I am just working on one stream, is it necessary to have views on all the other streams?

I am just trying to use clear case effectively, but it seems to accomplish simple tasks, there is a lot of overhead. Can anyone give any tips or advice on how to simplify the experience?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the [main differences between Git and ClearCase here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/645771/6309), to get you started.

> Use Case 1:

Yes, which is why it is advised to use one stream if possible, instead of the native "one stream per developer" model ([that I denounced here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1567308/6309))

> Use Case 2:

You can use some commands based on `lsco | ci`, [as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16732238/6309).
I detail that approach in "[Recursive checkin using Clearcase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/974016/6309)"

```
ct lsco -r -cvi -fmt "ci -nc \"%n\"\n" | ct
ct lsco -r -cvi -fmt "unco -rm %n\n" | ct
```

> Use Case 3:

Yes, you need to checkout a file, before modification and checkin, unless you modify it directly in a snapshot view, as an [hijacked file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28278764/6309); or in a dynamic view as [an eclipsed file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7799307/6309).
See for instance "[Eclipse not allowing to modify files without checkout in ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16589262/6309)" as an illustration of that issue.

> Use Case 4:

[cleartool mv](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mv.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-46&lang=en) will do that for you ([as I mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27062318/6309)), but you need to checkout the parent folder first.

> The directory where the element to be moved or renamed resides must be checked out. The destination directory must also be checked out; this directory may be the same as the source directory.

> Use Case 5:
>
> If I am just working on one stream, is it necessary to have views on all the other streams?

No, those views don't have to be started or even created.

Comment: Thanks so much VonC, this clears things up very much.