# Is it possible to list the views containing checked-out files in a vob?

Tags: clearcase

I know how to list all the checkouts in a single view with:

```
cleartool lscheckout -recurse
```

I want to be able to crossreference the checkouts against the views that made the checkout.

Is there a way to list which view an element was checked-out by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of lsco -long, when there is a lot of output, is not necessary human-friendly and depends on your location within the VOB in question.

To get a more friendly view, that will include files perhaps not visible in your current view,  try this:

```
cleartool lscheckout -all -fmt "%Tf\t%n\n" | sort
```

This will print all checked out versions, sorted by and leading with the view tag that checked out the version. This may be blank or have a UUID if the view is not tagged in the current registry region. You could also use %TUf to get the UUID (which is always present) and post process the UUID to get the view tag if available.

Comment: Thank you for this, it addresses my needs pretty much exactly. A departing team member has left many checkouts in multiple views and your solution addresses the need to sort by view tag.

Answer (score 1):

The [`cleartool lscheckout (lsco)`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lscheckout.htm) man page includes:

```
-l/ong
```

> Expands the listing to include the view to which the element is checked out.

So you should see the views having checked out those elements with:

```
ct lsco -r -l
```

Example:

```
M:\SC-II-def\aug2007\dira>cleartool lsco -l
2008-07-14T16:42:39-04:00 Denise Smith (user1.user@sc-II)
 checkout version "c.txt" from \main\1 (reserved)
 by view: SCII-snap
"sc-II:C:\clearcase_storage\viewstore\SCII-snap.vws")
```

(See in "[Uncheckout an element from a snapshot view when the view root directory is not accessible](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21313652)")

[Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4223401/brian-cowan) suggests [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52012059/6309) to use [`fmt_ccase`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm), which [I did in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28769165/6309).

The exact format is  `-fmt "%TUf\t%n\n"`, with

- `%TUf` the UUID of the view that holds the checkout
- `%Tf` the tag (if present in the current region)